gap within the brackets in css in VScode
It seems that Prettier is not removing gaps in my Brackets {} in CSS in VSCode latest Version.
I thought in the past it use to do it, not sure though. It formats in all other respects except removing gaps.
example
Input to prettier:
h1 {
  color: green



}

Desired output running Prettier:
h1 {
  color: green
}

I have tried reinstalling Prettier
